# Converting issue in java - xlsx to csv problem

Tags: java, csv, class, xlsx

I am currently working on a small program to automatically convert xlsx files to csv, but it does not really work.

It has an input file and an output file, the details are in the codesnippet.

You need the followings:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Can you please help me fix it? Thanks

```
static void convertToXlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
    // For storing data into CSV files
    StringBuffer cellValue = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row;
        Cell cell;

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            row = rowIterator.next();

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellValue.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellValue.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellValue.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        cellValue.append("" + ",");
                        break;

                    default:
                        cellValue.append(cell + ",");

                }
            }
        }

        fos.write(cellValue.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

static void convertToXls(File inputFile, File outputFile) {

    StringBuffer cellDData = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        Row row;

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            row = rowIterator.next();

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        cellDData.append("" + ",");
                        break;

                    default:
                        cellDData.append(cell + ",");
                }
            }
        }

        fos.write(cellDData.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File("C:\input.xls");
    File outputFile = new File("C:\output1.csv");
    File inputFile2 = new File("C:\\Users\\lendvaigy\\Desktop\\AKK\\DOWNLOAD TEST\\legjobb-eladasi-es-veteli-hozamok-arfolyamok.xlsx");
    File outputFile2 = new File("C:\\Users\\lendvaigy\\Desktop\\AKK\\DOWNLOAD TEST\\legjobb-eladasi-es-veteli-hozamok-arfolyamok.csv");
    convertToXls(inputFile, outputFile);
    convertToXlsx(inputFile2, outputFile2);
}
```

The main problem is that I am not a professional one, just a DIY rookie trying to create small programs.

Comment: When you say the program doesn't really work, what does it do and not do? Does it produce a file? Does it copy any of the XLSX contents to the CSV? Does it throw an error, if so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in **convertToXls()**. For converting xls to csv file use **XSSFWorkbook** instead of **HSSFWorkbook**. 
Try changing following in **convertToXls().**

```
static void convertToXls(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException {
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputFile.getPath());
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), true, "UTF-8");
    Sheet sheet =wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            boolean firstCell = true;
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (!firstCell)
                    out.print(',');
                String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                out.print(text);
                firstCell = false;
            }
            out.println();
    }
}
```

And rest should work as it is.

Comment: [HSSFWorkbook is used when working with XLS file format, XSSFWorkbook is used for XLSX format](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/). The method shouldn't really change since it's working with XLS files in that specific method

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.iterator
 at XlsxConvert.XlsxToCsv.convertToXls(XlsxToCsv.java:88)
 at XlsxConvert.XlsxToCsv.main(XlsxToCsv.java:136)
C:\Users\lendvaigy\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @Jorge That's probably because you've imported HSSFSheet rather than XSSFSheet. Check your imports and replace all HSSF stuff with XSSF where possible.

Comment: Now i changed everything to XSSF and now i get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - no suitable constructor found for XSSFWorkbook(java.io.FileInputStream)
    constructor org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.XSSFWorkbook(org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.io.FileInputStream cannot be converted to org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package)
    constructor org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.XSSFWorkbook(java.lang.String) is not applicable.........

Comment: what version of poi you are using?